# Trigger database update after control update on subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access form with a subform that allows updating data in table X.
The subform contains a text box control named Y, linked to column Y in table X.
Now I thought that the table would be updated immediately after that text box control loses focus, but I noticed that this only happens later, most probably after the subform loses focus.
The point is that I need the table to be updated before (or during) calling the sub Y_AfterUpdate, because I wish to perform some standard subs/functions that rely on the table to contain the new data.
What is the best way of achieving this table update? I applied subForm.Requery and that worked, but there may be another, more intuitive method available. Note that Requery to me sounds more like "populate controls of the subForm, using the current table contents", and not like "update table and then populate the subForm again". Hence, intuitively, I would have expected that I should have used another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
 DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```